# How should I formulate the multivariate regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, econometrics, model

Please see the logical flow of the issue in the figure. I want to examine the impact of economic factors (V1) on pollutant atmospheric deposition (V4).

[image]

We know economic activities (v1: x1~x3) may change pollutant's anthropogenic emissions (e1) which is one of the pollutant factors (V2: e1~e3). And the pollutant factors (V2) and meteorological factors (V3) together determine the pollutant atmospheric deposition (V4).

Can I form the regression formula as below? would the parameters of x1~x3 be the impact factors of economic factors on deposition?

> v4 ~ x1+x2+x3 + e1+e2+e3 + m1+m2+m3

or should I do it in three steps?

> step 1: e1 ~ x1+x2+x3
>
> step 2: V4 ~ e1+e2+e3 + m1+m2+m3
>
> step 3: multiply the parameters of x1~x3 from step 1 with the
> parameter of e1 in step 2.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Isn’t this the exact sort of situation where an instrumental variable would be used?

Comment: Hi Elizabeth. This almost seems to me like you need a simulation type model to capture the transmission of economic activity through to pollution. However, perhaps I am wrong and something along the lines of VECM would be useful, with an established long-run relationship. What literature are you basing your prospective model on?

Comment: @EB3112 hi, thank you for your comments, yes, I know of VECM, I have seen many papers that have used that model to simulate the processes from economic variable (V1) to anthropogenic emissions (e1), but not further. That's why I am not confident with my first solution because the economic impacts are not directly inserted on V4

Comment: @Dave thank you so much for the information, I'll read about it (I did not major in economics, so I lack some basic knowledge, but I am learning!)

Comment: Hi @Elizabeth. I think Dave might be alluding to a potential simultaneity bias that may be overcome with a sufficient instrument. Please correct me if I am wrong. Those are the only circumstances in which I have used IV in the past, but I know it has extensions for other types of endogenity. However, IV suffers the well-known challenge of it being difficult to properly specify an instrument.